# Run elasticsearch in terminal in any directory with command "elasticsearch"

Tags: macos, elasticsearch, terminal

On my previous Mac laptop I was able to run elasticsearch in terminal in any directory with the command "elasticsearch". Now I have to scroll to the elasticsearch install directory and run a particular file.

Could someone help me set up a command so I can just type "elasticsearch" wherever I am, and the service will start to run, as it was previously?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create an alias in your mac profile([latest version of mac uses .zshrc](https://www.theverge.com/2019/6/4/18651872/apple-macos-catalina-zsh-bash-shell-replacement-features)) like below.

Assuming you have installed Elasricsearch using the tar file as you mentioned you have to go to a particular dir(bin) in this case.

```
alias elasticsearch='./path/to/bin/foler/elasticsearch'
```

Please note, you need to run `source ~/.zshrc` to make sure alias is loaded. Let me know if you face any issue, help to help further.